# Webapp java synchronized object aquire

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

I have a situation in my  java, spring based web app. My server generates coupons ( a number mixed with alphabets , all random but unique)  , each coupon can be applied or used by  only one and only on logged in customer. They are shown on the front end to all the users, which then gets accepted/selected by the customers.But once accepted by one customer it gets assigned to him and not available to anyone else.

I tried to do synchronization of code block which checks if the coupon is already applied / availed, it worked but , cases like when two users click avail it at exact same time, it fails ( get allocated to both)

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use synchronization for this. You can store the state of the coupons in a database, and work on these data in a DB transaction, using locks. So:

- User tries the coupon, you get the ID
- Start a DB transaction, get the coupon row from it, and lock it
- Do what you need to, then invalidate the coupon
- End the DB transaction, release the lock

The database do not necessarly need to be a standalone RDMS, in a simple case, even SQLite is sufficient. Anyway, DBs most certainly handle race conditions betten than you (or most of us) can.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer avoid database transactions you can use a Set with all the generated coupons and a set referencing only available coupons. When a user select a coupon in a synch block remove the coupon from available ones. The second user then fail to obtain it